# DAAB and ref cursors, Why no up to date tutorials?

Tags: .net, stored-procedures, daab, enterprise-library-5, ref-cursor

Why are there no up to date tutorials books, or anything like that online for working with enterprise library 5.0 and Oracle ref cursors?  Is there no one on Earth who needs help with that?  I am absolutely dumbfounded.  There was a way to do it in older versions, but the functionality of some objects has been taken out and it doesn't seem to have been replaced.  Example, AddCursorOutParameter is a method in the old DAAB which added output params to the database command object.  That method doesn't exist in the current DAAB...  It seemed infinitely usefull.  Why on earth isn't it in the latest version...  Cause right now that is exactly what I am struggling with.  I have spent a couple of days trying to get this done the right way, and this is definitely going to make my project run over time.

How do you deal with ref cursors in .net when trying to call stored procedures that return ref cursors using Enterprise Library 5.0?  If anybody has any answers whatsoever, I would be happy to hear them.  Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a null placeholder: http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2007/08/27/enterprise-library-and-oracle-stored-procedure-record-sets/

You have to use a [parameter array list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748722%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), you cannot use the AddParameter.

Answer (score 1):

The soulution outlined here:
http://devstuffs.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/enterprise-library-5-with-odp-net/
woked for me.